# Dynamic HTTP request in Gatling

Tags: scala, jmeter, gatling

I am moving from Jmeter to Gatling for some comparison of results. As I am new to SCALA I am no table to map the dynamic request values in the HTTP rquest. 
This is what I did in Jmeter

```
<stringProp name="script">int threadNo = ctx.getThreadNum(); 
int base = ${starting_hhid};
int hhId = (threadNo) + base;
int serialNo = (threadNo) + ${starting_serialNum};
vars.put(&quot;hhId&quot;, Integer.toString(hhId));
vars.put(&quot;serialNum&quot;, Integer.toString(serialNo));
</stringProp> 
... 
<stringProp name="HTTPSampler.path">
 `enter code here`${serverPath_g1}/1/${hhId}/dmxs/${serialNum}/events</stringProp>
```

Here I was passing hhId and serialNum dynamically at the run time. So these where changing all the time.

```
${serverPath_g1}/1/1/dmxs/1/events`enter code here`
${serverPath_g1}/1/2/dmxs/2/events
${serverPath_g1}/1/3/dmxs/3/events
```

I want to do the same in Gatling. Any suggestions or example??

Comment: I want to try something like below
val postEventsHttp = http("post user")
    .post("/${hhId}/dmxs/${serial}/events")
    .body(StringBody(userString))
    .check(status is 200)
Where serial and hhId can be set at run time. So for example I am executing this for 10 times, all the 10 times the value will be changed.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy.  If you run your gatling test via a dockerized Taurus, then you can pass env variables that the Scala script can accces:

```
OSX_HOST=`ipconfig getifaddr en0`
docker run -it --rm -e MY_PORT='8888' --add-host "taurus-host:${OSX_HOST}" \
 -v $PWD:/bzt-configs -v $PWD:/tmp/artifacts blazemeter/taurus:latest \
 /tmp/artifacts/performance.yml
```

Then, in your Scala script, you can get the variable:

```
val myPort = sys.env.get("MY_PORT")
val targetHost = "http://taurus-host:" + myPort.getOrElse("80")
```